# Anti-symmetric line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I have the following line integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$
$$
\int_C \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy\right)
$$
for a (known) piece-wise smooth curve $C$, and a (known) differentiable function $f$. Can anything be said, in general, about such an integral?

Comment: By Green, it is $-\iint_D \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}\,dx\,dy$.

Comment: If you are referring to Green's Theorem, that requires the curve to be closed, which in this case it is not.

Comment: Then even less can be said.